# File Encryption C#

Tags: c#, encryption

I found this code on-line I want to know what do pass in this program what is this output and input strings are ? I am passing input as a file name and output as path but it`s giving error.

```
private void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    try
    {
        string password = @"myKey123"; // Your Key Here
        UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

        string cryptFile = outputFile;
        FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

        RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

        int data;
        while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
            cs.WriteByte((byte)data);

        fsIn.Close();
        cs.Close();
        fsCrypt.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Encryption failed!", "Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: ... that is because you eat the exception. Remove the try-catch for debugging purposes, or change the catch clause to catch all exceptions (`catch (Exception ex)`), set a breakpoint and inspect the exception.

Comment: try to catch Exception in the catch statment

Comment: `catch(Exception ex) { /* capture message & paste into the question*/ }`

Comment: @AustinSalonen `catch(Exception ex) { /* capture message & paste into Google */ }` FTFY.

Comment: Error after putting catch (Exception ex)) is "Could not find a part of the path " and after that there is the path .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `outputFile` parameter isn't a path but rather the fully qualified file name that it needs to write to.  An example way to call this code is:

`EncryptFile(@"c:\temp\unencryptedfile.txt", @"c:\temp\encryptedfile.txt");`

Barring that, replace the `catch` code with the following:

```
catch(Exception ex) {
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // will show the top exception
  if (ex.InnerException != null) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message); // will show additional details if present
  }
}
```

---

**side note**: just so you know, the code you have leaks memory.  You might want to investigate the `using` clause and look up which of the classes you are using implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Yeah Thanks Chris that works fine and one more thing what if I do not want to use key in my program. Can I just remove the string password ?

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper: encryption requires a key; you can't remove that.